# Letting control flow go backwards (up) in an if-statement, is it possible?

Tags: matlab, if-statement, break, control-flow

Note: I am programming in Matlab, but this is a general question so presumably any pseudocode should answer my question. I would like to know, how can I go back to a previous block of an if-statement, depending on the results of subsequent if-statements?

Here is my motivation: I have a program that makes a new folder to write to, and if that folder exists already I want the program to ask first before overwriting it.  If the users says yes the folder is overwritten, if they say no the program terminates without overwriting.  If the user says something other than yes or no, I want go back to the control block that asks whether to overwrite or not. Otherwise, if the user makes a mistake at the yes/no section they have to run the program all over again in order to save their work. This backwards control flow would be easy to implement in a for-loop with a continue-statement, but continue-statements are not valid within an if-statement.

Here is some example code of what I have now:

```
 confirm = input('Warning: That filepath already exists! Continuing may overwrite 
data saved there. Continue(Y/N)?', 's');

        if strcmpi(confirm, 'Y')                        %Compare to Y, case insensitive
        elseif strcmpi(confirm,'N')                 %Compare to N, case insensitive
                display('Program terminated without saving data');
                return;
        else
               display('Error: Enter Y or N');         %User error, end program        
               return;
        end
```

If they enter Y (or y) the loop does nothing, if they enter N (or n) the program ends, if they enter anything else they get an error and the program also ends.  Instead of ending, I want to go back to the input step and redefine 'confirm'.  Is it possible to "rewind" or break from if-statements like this?

Comment: I'd say put it in a function and recursively call itself again or use some kind of loop.  Make the text of confirm the parameter if calling itself recursively, perhaps

Comment: [`while`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/while.html) loop?

Comment: @ Mattsjo Yes that sounds like it would work, I was just hoping that there was some kind of common keyword I could use instead of defining a separate function. Like the rewind() command but for the current program, not a file.  I guess this question is actually more language-specific than I realized when I asked it.

Comment: @ horchler Are you suggesting encasing the whole thing in an always-true while(1) loop that only breaks when a valid input is entered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for anything fancy:

```
confirm = input('Warning: That filepath already exists! Continuing may overwrite
data saved there. Continue(Y/N)?', 's');
inputY = 0; % False to start 
inputN = 0;
while ~inputY && ~inputN
    inputN = strcmpi(confirm, 'N');
    if (inputN) 
        display('Program terminated without saving data');
        return;
    end

    inputY = strcmpi(confirm, 'Y');
    if (inputY)
        % Do whatever

    end

    confirm = input('Please enter (Y/N)', 's');
end
enter code here
```

Comment: I like it, I think that's what horchler was suggesting above.

Comment: Actually there's a problem with this, the line `confirm = input('Please enter (Y/N)', 's');` is always displayed once. I implemented by putting everything inside the while loop into one if loop, then putting that last confirm line into the `else` block